# call java method from native code(not JNI )

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

i want to call java method through shell .

main(argc,argv)   call->   JAVA Md5

so i need call java method from the native code . but there isn't JNIEnv or JVM in pure native code .    How could  add JVM to the native code .

Comment: _call java method from native code(not JNI )_ Why did you tag JNI then?

Comment: i means no java call native code .. then  native code call java method . on this occasion , native code has a JNIEnv pointer . ~~~

Comment: But why do you need java md5? Wouldn't any md5 hash algo do?

Comment: just a example ...  java md5 means any java method .

Answer (score 0):

[Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside) might be what you're looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/

It's using GPLv2 as its license